# How to update existing records and upsert new records

Tags: apex, trigger, upsert, insert

I want to update existing task records but a new record gets created instead . What am I doing wrong.

Apex:

```
public static void Activities(List<Account> accounts) {
  Set<Id> persAccIds = (new Map<Id, Account> (accounts)).keySet();

  set<id> TaskWhatIDs = new set<id> ();
  for (Task t :[Select WhatId from Task where Subject = 'Sending' and Status != 'Completed' and whatId IN :persAccIds]) {
    TaskWhatIDs.add(t.whatId);
  }
      System.debug('persAccIds: ' + persAccIds);
              System.debug('soql: ' + [select id, PersonEmail, FirstName, LastName, SsoId__c, PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE id IN :persAccIds]);


  List<Task> taskList = [Select id FROM Task where id IN :TaskWhatIDs];
  for (Account acc : [select id, PersonEmail, FirstName, LastName, SsoId__c, PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE id IN :persAccIds]) {
    //if (TaskWhatIDs.contains(acc.Id))
    //continue;
           System.debug('acc: ' + acc);

    Profile Obj = new Profile(acc);
    Task gTask = new Task();
    gTask.Status = 'Not Started';
    gTask.Description = System.JSON.serialize(Obj);
    gTask.WhoId = acc.PersonContactId;
    gTask.WhatId = acc.Id;
    gTask.Subject = 'Send';
    taskList.add(gTask);
  }

  if (taskList.size() > 0) {
      System.debug('taskList: ' + taskList);
    upsert taskList;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not binding an ID with the new instance of Task which you're creating in `for` loop. Something like this: `gTask.id = task.id;`

Comment: Are you trying to update accounts's tasklist?

Comment: @rahulgawale That is what I want to achieve indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have two queries on Task object, rather you can get them in a single query on account object.

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT id, (SELECT WhatId FROM Tasks where Subject = 'Sending' and Status != 'Completed') FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accounts];
Task[] taskList = new List<Task>();
for (Account acc : accounts){
    for(Task taskObj: acc.Tasks){
        /// Update the fields here
    }
    taskList.addAll(acc.Tasks);
}
//...
update taskList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this sort of code if there is only ever one `Task` at most per `Account`:

```
Map<Id, Task> whatIdToTasks = Map<Id, Task>();
for (Task t : [...]) {
    whatIdToTasks.put(t.whatId, t);
}

for (Account acc : [...]) {
    // Update existing Task or create new one
    Task gTask = whatIdToTasks.get(acc.Id);
    if (gTask == null) gTask = new Task(Id = acc.Id);
    ...
}
```